# How to Create and Associate a Category to a Contact using EWS Managed API 2.2

Tags: categories, exchangewebservices, contacts

Is it possible to create a Category Item Object and Associate it with a Contact using the EWS Managed API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a Category to any Object in a Mailbox using the Categories property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.categories(v=exchg.80).aspx .

For a particular color/description to be show in Outlook or OWA the category you pass in must match an Item in the Master category list. You can read/modify the Master category list in a Mailbox using EWS eg https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5c5f072-0b5c-49ce-9db7-57f76f5e011e/edit-master-category-list-in-exchange-2010-via-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3917500-2bbc-4def-98b4-696e49efed6f/adding-categories-to-a-users-master-category-list-in-exchange-2010-using-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Comment: I am already was aware of these samples but it appears that there is not very much documentation regarding Categories/Category objects in Exchange or Outlook Client. Over the years and versions of Exchange and and the Outlook Client it has never been clearly described how to manage Categories relative to Contact, Email Messages, Task, Appointment and Calendar objects. The best reference I've found regarding the use of Category/Categories is the book "Programming Applications for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007." I am looking to extend the current use-model of Categories in Outlook.

Comment: Hey Glen I did find what I was looking (Thank you!) for after all in one of the references you sent; I had to re-read it again. What was confusing is the term "MasterCategoryList" as it is not formally part of the Outlook/Exchange. The trick and secret, unfortunately, the hidden "CategoryList" directory under the "Calendar" parent.

Comment: `You can assign a Category` - how do you do that? Do you need to update the server after merely set it in the email item?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while looking to update the master category list using EWS, but not the Managed API. In case anyone else is looking to do the same thing, here's the solution I came up with, which uses Python and requests:

```
import base64
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth


# Create the XML request template for EWS
payload = r"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:UpdateUserConfiguration>
      <t:UserConfigurationName Name="CategoryList">
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar">
        <t:Mailbox>
        <t:EmailAddress>your_email@your_domain.com</t:EmailAddress>
        <t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType>
        <t:MailboxType>Mailbox</t:MailboxType>
        </t:Mailbox>
        </t:DistinguishedFolderId>
      </t:UserConfigurationName>
      <t:XmlData>{}</t:XmlData>
    </m:UpdateUserConfiguration>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""

# Create the categories XML
# Colors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxocfg/eb7cac90-6200-4ac3-8f3c-6c808c681c8b
xml_data = r"""<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <categories default="First category" xmlns="CategoryList.xsd">
  <category name="First category" color="1" />
  <category name="Second category" color="2" />
  </categories>"""

# Encode the payload and insert it into the XML request
xml = base64.b64encode(xml_data.encode())
payload = payload.replace('{}', str(xml).strip('b\''))

# Use requests with the NTLM authentication libary to submit the request
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
ews_url = 'https://mail.your-organizations-exchange-server.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx'
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(exhange_username, exchange_password)
response = session.post(ews_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```